# Migrate map Issue

Tags: migrations

This is a weird issue with the Migrate module 2.6
I'm migrating a users table "mysql" database to a test node and I'm getting a error with the migration map
here is the error :

```
Migration failed with source plugin exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.migrate_map_usersmigration map ON u.user_id = map.sourceid1 WHERE ( (map.source' at line 1
```

and here is my code:

```
class UsersMigration extends myBaseMigrationClass {

  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $this->description = t('Just for testing');

    $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'mydb')
      ->select('users', 'u')
      ->fields('u', array('user_id', 'full_name', 'birthday'));

    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);

    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('test');

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap(
    $this->machineName,
      array(
        'user_id' => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'alias' => 'u',
        ),
      ),
      MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
    );

    $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'full_name');
  }
}
```

Do I'm doing something wrong here?

- Also to clarify, the source query is working fine and I'm getting the correct data out when I print it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to find a solution for this weird issue, according to the Migration examples (beer, Wine) modules. the code I have posted above should work fine, However it's throwing that weird error. it turns out that I needed to pass the database name again like this:

```
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap(
$this->machineName,
  array(
    'user_id' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'alias' => 'u',
    ),
  ),
  MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema(),
 'mydbName'
);
```

even the example modules that using SqlSource class wont work with migrate "7.x-2.6-rc1+57-dev". I will try to report that issue to the developer

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this issue.

I tried to do the same actions on another machine. The problem does not occur there, which is very strange. I suspect this is a problem with my LAMP stack (native OS X Mavericks stack).

So it could be your PHP version, try upgrading it.

See [Migrate examples failing](https://www.drupal.org/node/2379575#comment-9363219)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you please improve your answer by summarizing the key elements of your link.